# angular 2 check validity when no covering ngform

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-forms, angularjs-ng-form

```
  <input  matInput  [(ngModel)]="testDate" (ngModelChange)="mychange($event)" [value]="minDate" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]...
```

I dont have a covering ngform or submit button. In myChange() how can I check if testDate is valid. (just like if there was a covering form/control group we can do form.isvalid..to enable/disable the submit button

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best way for you to do that is to put your field inside a form. But you can work around it, and add some validation for the change event, maybe testing if it is null, or if it is an empty string or if it's a valid date object. Then, use a Boolean field and assign to it the result of the validation and use that field on your button.

```
<button (click)="callMyCallBackFunction($event)" [disabled]="myValidationInputField"></button>
```

Comment: Problem is the material date picker allows user to type a date. Typing just 11 binds to a value of Nov 01, 2001 but the component does turn red indicating invalid date which is cool. Hate to go the ngform, control group route just to validate one single field. I have no other validation on the component.

Comment: You could make the input read-only: `<input readonly matInput ...>` - that way only valid dates can be selected.

Comment: When the date is far in the future or past it helps just typing it in versus clicking next prev in the drop down.